# How to get list of mongodb databases and collections list from a ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am using Rails 3 and Mongoid gem. But I need to fill a combobox with the list of mongodb databases. In mongodb shell we can list databases with "show dbs" command. Also there is getDBNameList()  and db.getCollectionNames() commands in mongodb drivers. But I could not figure out how to use these commands from a ruby on rails app.

Also I wonder; if I can get databases and collections list with using mongoid gem. Because I am sure that I had read that mongoid supports using more than one database, but I think it was model dependent.

So what do you think; is there any solution or I have to use mongo-ruby-driver gem, not mongoid.

Answer (score 16):

In mongoid 3

```
Mongoid.default_session.collections # returns the collections
```

I usually extract the names as follows:

```
Mongoid.default_session.collections.map(&:name).sort
```

Comment: default_session is default_client in mongo 5

Answer (score 10):

You can do the following using the mongo ruby driver:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'

connection = Mongo::Connection.new("localhost")
connection.database_names.each do |name|
  db = connection.db(name)
  db.collections.each do |collection|
    puts "#{name} - #{collection.name}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier to get the [Mongo::DB](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/lib/mongo/db.rb) out of the Mongoid config:

```
db = Mongoid::Config.master
db.collection_names
```

Comment: we can configure all the databases in Mongoid (via mongoid.yml) dbs = Mongoid.databases dbs.each do |db| db.collections end

Comment: connection = Mongoid.master.connection connection.database_names #=> Get an array of names db = connection.database("name") #=> Get a specific db object db.collections #=> Get an array of collections ##### I think this is the best way; Thanks to durran (from github).

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me (on mongoid 3.x): `NoMethodError: undefined method \`master' for Mongoid::Config:Module`

Comment: I had the same problem than @turboladen, any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: @DavidSilveira: unfortunately I couldn't tell you if I did or not--it's been a long time since I've worked with that app.  Good luck to you though!

Answer (score 2):

A short version.

```
db = Mongoid.master
db.collection_names
```

Comment: How would you do this with Mongoid 3.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

I used following code to list all collection and fields, provided the list of mongo db databases mentioned in *mongoid.yml*

```
def printDb(dbUri)
    puts "#{dbUri}"
    client = Mongo::Client.new(dbUri)
    # List all collections in the current database
    #collections = client.database.list_collections.map(&:name)
    collections = client.database.list_collections
    # Print the collection names
    collections.each do |collection|
            begin
                puts "  collection- #{collection[:name]}"
                colln=client[ collection[:name] ]
                #fields = collection.find_one.keys
                #fields = collection.find.limit(1).keys
                fields = colln.find.first.keys
            puts "      Fields: #{fields}"
            puts "" 
        rescue
            puts "      ** error in looking for a collection **"
            puts "" 
        end
    end
end

uriList=['mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/my_app_db1',
    'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/my_app_db2', 
    'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/my_app_db3', 
    'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/my_app_db4'
     ]

#call function 
uriList.each do |myUri|
    printDb(myUri)
end
```

The parts of URI can be changed as per your yml file configurations. It may require *mongo* and *mongoid* gems