# Ruby and MongoDB - Retrieve Database and Collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

From within my rails app, how can I retrieve the MongoDB database (and its collections) it's connected to?

Pls note that i don't want to list the databases. I want only the one the app is connected to!

Comment: are you using an ODM like https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid?

Comment: This is a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142900/how-to-get-list-of-mongodb-databases-and-collections-list-from-a-ruby-on-rails-a

Comment: @AdamComerford no its not. I don't want to list the databases. I want to know which database the app is connected to. If this were to be a .Net app, i'm asking which connection string is being use to run my queries...

Comment: OK, so where in your code do you do the equivalent of `db = connection.db(name)`? - the name is the current database you are connected to, and the only different between your question and the one I linked is that you would only do a single iteration of the collections loop. All the code for what you want to do is in the answer, it's just not *exactly* what you are looking for. I would still argue that it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

- You should probably use an ODM: https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid
- Setup config/mongoid.yml as per [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#ruby-mongoid-tutorial).
- `include Mongoid::Document` in the model.
- After which, you can just query as per Rails way~ `results = Foo.where(name: "bar")`

Comment: I don't want to query the collection. I want to know which database is my app connected to...